# Add basic Authorization to Angular 7 POST

Tags: angular

Here is my code:

```
let authorizationData = 'Basic ' + btoa('username' + ':' + 'password');
const headerOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': authorizationData
        })
    };
return this.http.post(`URL`, {}, headerOptions);
```

I am getting the following in the Console:
**OPTIONS 'URL' net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

The request headers look like this:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/register
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
```

When I check headerOptions in the Console it looks a bit strange to me:

```
headerOptions: Object
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0)
size: (...)
```

Don't see the actual values I am creating.
Please help me to understand how all of this works.

Thanks.

Comment: `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` is a HTTPS error. You don't have a valid SSL certificate. Nothing to do with authorisation. See [How do I deal with NET:ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome)

Comment: I would think so too, but the same thing works fine in Postman.